# powershell get-aduser query to grab all groups with two strings

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Main purpose is to get a list of all Active directory groups that pertains to my work location within the corporation.  I have two strings to search for.  DC## (which is the DC I work at) and TOWN_NAME (the town/location where I work).  Most of our distribution and security groups contain the ## of the DC, while a few have only TOWN_NAME in the name of the group.

Within my long script, I have the following that is pertinent to this question:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "*##*"} -SearchBase "ou=ou,ou=ou,dc=domain=dc=com"
```

That works great for getting the majority of the groups and exporting it to excel.  However, I was wondering how I can put in an "or" statement to include TOWN_NAME with wildcards before/after so it'll grab all groups with either the ## or TOWN_NAME in the group's name.

I've tried positioning the "or" statement in several different places, but it will not work.  The next thing I could do is just to have the whole script from "Get-ADGroup" down be copied and past so it runs twice, but if there's an easier/quicker way, I'd prefer that.

Comment: `-filter {name -like "*##*" -OR name -like "*TOWN_NAME*"}`

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  I knew that I could put the "OR" in between the two, but I forgot about the dash.  That was what was killing my script.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: More info on filtering, supplementing Zach's comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/14/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter-part-ii/.   @Zach85, you might want to do an Answer with a bit more info on filtering.  Could change his question title to something more generic, if there isn't an answer already out there for general `Get-ADUserGroup` searching.